# Highlighting won't change when using hi def link

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a basic custom syntax file for the first time, but I noticed that after I set a highlight link it's basically set and I'm not really sure how to change it.
Here is my syntax file:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    echom "Quitting"
    finish
endif

syn keyword tTask       task start fix 
syn keyword tEnd        finish
syn keyword tNote       note

hi def link tTask Special
hi def link tEnd Todo
hi def link tNote Comment

let b:current_syntax = "todo"
```

In my `.vimrc`, I have `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.todo setfiletype todo`.
When I change `Comment` to `Special` for example, the highlighting won't change in a file I've created. In fact... not much I've tried changes it. Is this a common problem? I couldn't find this online.

Edit: I "reopen" the todo file by using `:edit` in the tab, but closing and reopening in a new instance gives the same result where the highlighting doesn't change. I have put in `echom` commands, so I know that the code is running when I run `:edit` or open a new instance, but the highlighting doesn't change.

Comment: Are you editing the syntax file and then expecting a change? Or are you running a new highlight command? Exact steps/details would be helpful in pinning down what you expect vs. what's happening and how to get there. (I wouldn't recommend putting an `echom` in a syntax file. Also note that you can use the `ftdetect` directory for new filetypes. And that `unlet` statement seems spurious to me? You might also include a _minimal_ vimrc with your problem; see [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) for help reducing it.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I am editing the syntax file (changing `Comment` to `Special`) and then re-opening a `test.todo` file I have created. I've put in `echom` commands in, and I know it runs, but nothing changes in the `test.todo` file. The `unlet` statement was a mistake (I had removed its matching `let` statement earlier), so I will update the question. The only relevant line in my vimrc is the `autocmd` statement that sets the `todo` filetype.

Comment: Define « re-opening ». Are you running `:edit` or opening a brand new vim instance? Please [edit] the question so this information does not get lost in the comments.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Just added the information - sorry, I'm new to stackexchange forums.

Comment: No worries, welcome to [vi.se]! If you haven't already, the [tour] and [help] are good places to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you link groups using `default` it will only has effect once.

This is designed that way to provide default highlighting and possibility for end user to override it in their configs.

1. syntax file provides some sane defaults
2. user doesn't like it and overrides with `hi link group1 group2`
3. syntax file using `default` doesn't override it back whenever syntax file is sourced again.

For your design phase, when you're not sure about what would be the best "sane" default there are several ways:

1. `:syn off` and then `:syn on`
2. or remove `default` from your `hi` definitions (but don't forget to return them once you're satisfied with result and want to distribute your syntax file)

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. I looked through the vim help for `highlight` and couldn't find any of this. Thank you so much!